# XML Data Fetching Code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, zoho

I have one .xml file which code is as follows.....

```
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/getMyRecords">
<result>
<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="LEADID">967993000000074003</FL>
<FL val="Company">fff</FL>
<FL val="First Name">fffff</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">fffff</FL>
</row>
<row no="2">
<FL val="LEADID">967993000000074001</FL>
<FL val="Company">PHI</FL>
<FL val="First Name">San</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">Raut</FL>
</row>....
```

so now i want to fetch value from this file which val attribute is Company, First Name, Last Name and LEADID.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Also, there is no program code whatsoever in your question. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: http://php.net/simplexmlelement

Comment: You have to load it in DOMDocument and then use DOMXPath for this

Comment: Have you actually tried to search google for the 2 words "PHP XML"? There's tons of results for exactly what you want.

Comment: Ya sure..... i try the following code..... $xml = file_get_contents( "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/getMyRecords?scope=crmapi&authtoken=xxx");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $xml );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

foreach ($xml->result->Leads->row as $t) {
  foreach ($t->FL as $rr) {
    echo $rr."<br />";  
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is probably the easiest way of doing this.

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData);
```

then to get the items you want is easy as pie..

```
foreach($data->Leads->row as $row)
{
    switch($row['val'])
    {
        case 'Company': //do something with the data
         break;
        case 'First Name': //do something with the data
         break;
        case 'Last Name': //do something with the data
         break;
        case 'LEADID': //do something with the data
         break;
    }
}
```

for more infor see [SimpleXML in the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)